# usb boot controller not found

Tags: boot, usb, macbook-pro

I have recently purchased a 2009 macbook pro with Yosemite...I want ubuntu and loaded a usb from third party (unetbootin). when I boot from the usb it tells me it can't open but then goes to the menu (try ubuntu, install ubuntu and a couple others) I have tried both of the first two (try and install) yet each time it stops on no controller found. I have also tried this from both usb ports and have made sure disc encryption is turned off.
Please help me get back to my ubuntu I really miss it!

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact error message?

Comment: So I just erased the usb and reloaded it in case it was an issue with it...I went to unetbootin and loaded the one for mac and when it finished it stated  (the created usb device will not boot off a mac, insert into a pc, and select the usb boot option in the bios boot menu) I downloaded the one that stated for mac what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `nomodest` parameter in the kernel settings on startup. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) tutorial details the process of adding this parameter while booting from live USB/CD.

Comment: this is all pertaining to Ubuntu terminal it seems to me...My machine is apple MacBook pro that I am trying to install Ubuntu. I don't have access to kernel or am I not understanding?

Comment: while you boot from ubuntu live USB, click any key to see more options from where you can select `nomodest` parameter. Refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152847/how-to-access-boot-options-12-04-live-usb) thread to know more.