# SOLVED Black Screen when Booting

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am new to Linux for the most part, I have worked with the cli, but I have never installed in on a system before. I just got a new computer and I decided that I wanted to install Ubuntu on it for practice as well as expand my horizons.

I have a Ubuntu 17.04 on a Live USB drive. I tried to install but when it went passed the Ubuntu loading screen, it just displayed a black screen. I tried booting from the USB stick instead of installing but the most I get is a quick flash of the desktop and then black.

I saw a couple of posts saying that I should go through GRUB and boot in recovery mode, but no matter what I try (shift, esc, space, etc.) I cannot enter the GRUB menu. I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: Try booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter

Comment: How do i do that without entering the GRUB menu?

Comment: You find that right here when booting from your Live USB:  https://askubuntu.com/a/152872/231142

Comment: I'm an idiot. My splash screen didn't look like the splash screen pictured in that comment, so I was thinking I had to pull up a different menu as opposed to editing from the command line. Thanks, that helped me get where I needed to go.

Comment: In any case, there is a definite answer here about this problem : https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it