# Ubuntu not installing on intel NUC 6i7KYK

Tags: boot, usb, intel-nuc

am having problems trying to install ubuntu on intel NUC6i7KYK. windows 10 installs OK so hardware is functioning. my intel NUC6i7KYK has 1x16GB memory (Kingston KVR21S15D8/16) and 1TB Samsung SSD960EVO.

- the BIOS is update to the latest (46) from intel site.
- have followed the intel recommendation for BIOS settings.
- when i try to boot off a live USB ubuntu, the USB is recognized as a valid boot device and i get the screen giving me options to try ubuntu, install ubuntu etc. but no matter what i select, there is a fleeting message "mmco": unkown controller version(3). You may experience propblems" and then after some kernel messages the screen goes blank after about 2 minutes. have waited for an hour or more but no luck.
- have tried ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 16.10, 17.04,  Gentoo, OpenSuse and all with the same problem that the screen goes blank and never comes back.

the problem has been faced by others but havent seen a solution.

Will appreciate any help. right now i am back to windows 10 and that loads and runs fine.

thanks a lot.

/bazmi.

Answer (score 1):

OK. i have been able to solve the problem with the help of two posts.

once the USB boot brings you to the screen where you have the option of trying ubuntu or installing ubuntu, the post

[How to Access Boot Options 12.04 Live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152847/how-to-access-boot-options-12-04-live-usb/152872#152872)

is very helpful.

this allowed me to install Ubuntu.

once installed, the post

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

gives instructions to make the changes permanent and then on it is OK.

now i have Ubuntu 17.04 up on my intel NUC6i7KYK

Thanks.

/bazmi.