# DMAR Firmware bug no firmware reserved region can cover this

Tags: bios, intel-nuc

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the intel nuc6i7kyk. When I start the installation, it says DMAR Firmware bug no firmware reserved region can cover this and then the screen turns black and I can't do anything.

I tried searching for a bios update but I found nothing on the Intel website.
The current version of the BIOS I have is KYSKLi70.86A.0074.2021.1029.0102

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DMAR firmware bug. Broken BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit more and found a solution by combining these 2 answers but it still not working completely :

[How to Access Boot Options 12.04 Live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152847/how-to-access-boot-options-12-04-live-usb/152872#152872)

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

Basically, to access the boot option, press shift directly after the BIOS menu appears
Then press e to edit the boot and add "nomodeset"

And then once installed add this option to /etc/default/grub, firstly:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
and then add nomodeset to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

I can boot with this but the system does then not use the GPU and the sound over Hdmi does not work...